# Intel XDK - Aplicação ramal como um soft phone

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

Desenvolvi uma aplicação com o Intel XDK para uso interno em rede local, que é responsável em listar todos os ramais da empresa, gostaria de implementar no click dos itens da lista a funcionalidade de ligar para o ramal, usando a tecnologia SIP - Session Initiation Protocol.

Resumindo, o usuário clica no item da lista e o aplicativo liga para o ramal

Encontrei referencias na internet, mas as documentações que não me ajudaram muito.

Referências da tecnologia SIP;

**JsSip** - http://jssip.net/

**sipML** - https://www.doubango.org/sipml5/

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Creio que sua pergunta está fechada porque não está clara sua dúvida. Qual o problema com seu código? O que exatamente você quer saber? Seria apenas um exemplo ou documentação?

Comment: @utluiz, estou perguntando como implementar esta funcionalidade SIP em minha aplicação, então seria um exemplo.